# Proper Indexing MySQL Table

Tags: mysql

I can't seem to get this query to perform any faster than **8 hours**! 0_0
I have read up on indexing and I am still not sure I am doing this right.

I am expecting my query to calculate a value for `BROK_1_RATING` based on dates and other row values - **500,000 records**.

**Using record #1 as an example - my query should:**

- get all other records that have the same `ESTIMID`
- ignore records where `ANALYST` =""
- ignore records where `ID` is the same as record being compared i.e.
  `ID` != 1
- the records must fall within a time frame 
  i.e. BB.`ANNDATS_CONVERTED` <= `working`.`ANNDATS_CONVERTED`, 
  BB.`REVDATS_CONVERTED` > `working`.`ANNDATS_CONVERTED`
- BB.`IRECCD` must = 1
- Then count the result
- Then write the count value to the `BROK_1_RATING` column for record #1
- now do same for record#2, and #3 and so on for the entire table

In human terms - "Examine the date of record #1 - Now, within time frame from record #1 - count the number of times the number 1 exists with the same brokerage `ESTIMID`, do not count record #1, do not count blank `ANALYST` rows. Move on to record #2 and do the same"

---

```
UPDATE `working` SET `BROK_1_RATING` = 

    (SELECT COUNT(`ID`) FROM (SELECT `ID`, `IRECCD`, `ANALYST`,  `ESTIMID`, `ANNDATS_CONVERTED`, `REVDATS_CONVERTED` FROM `working`) AS BB 

        WHERE 
            BB.`ANNDATS_CONVERTED` <= `working`.`ANNDATS_CONVERTED` 
        AND 
            BB.`REVDATS_CONVERTED` > `working`.`ANNDATS_CONVERTED`
        AND 
            BB.`ID` != `working`.`ID`
        AND 
            BB.`ESTIMID` = `working`.`ESTIMID`
        AND
            BB.`ANALYST` != ''
        AND
            BB.`IRECCD` = 1
    )

WHERE `working`.`ANALYST` != '';
```

---

```
| ID | ANALYST |   ESTIMID    | IRECCD | ANNDATS_CONVERTED | REVDATS_CONVERTED |  BROK_1_RATING  | NO_TOP_RATING |  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |  DAVE   | Brokerage000 |   4    |    1998-07-01     |    1998-07-04     |                 |      3        |
| 2  |  DAVE   | Brokerage000 |   1    |    1998-06-28     |    1998-07-10     |                 |      4        |
| 3  |  DAVE   | Brokerage000 |   5    |    1998-07-02     |    1998-07-08     |                 |      2        |
| 4  |  DAVE   | Brokerage000 |   1    |    1998-07-04     |    1998-12-04     |                 |      3        |
| 5  |  SAM    | Brokerage000 |   1    |    1998-06-14     |    1998-06-30     |                 |      4        |
| 6  |  SAM    | Brokerage000 |   1    |    1998-06-28     |    1999-08-08     |                 |      4        |
| 7  |         | Brokerage000 |   1    |    1998-06-28     |    1999-08-08     |                 |      5        |
| 8  |  DAVE   | Brokerage111 |   2    |    1998-06-28     |    1999-08-08     |                 |      3        |
```

**'EXPLAIN'** results:

```
id| select_type        | table            | type  | possible_keys | key                   | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 | PRIMARY            | working          | index | ANALYST       | PRIMARY               | 4       | NULL  | 467847 | Using where
2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | <derived3>       | ALL   | NULL          | NULL                  | NULL    | NULL  | 467847 | Using where
3 | DERIVED            | working          | index | NULL          | test_combined_indexes | 226     | NULL  | 467847 | Using index
```

I have indexes on the single columns - and as well - have tried multiple column index like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `working` ADD INDEX `test_combined_indexes` (`IRECCD`, `ID`, `ANALYST`, `ESTIMID`, `ANNDATS_CONVERTED`, `REVDATS_CONVERTED`) COMMENT '';
```

Comment: Basic rule of thumb: Any field used in a decision context, ie. where, join, order by, group by, etc... should have an index on it.

Comment: Why all the sub-queries? Can you take a step back and explain the tables involved and what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hi @Marc B - thanks. I have indexes on all the columns really. I cant be  sure that the query is actually using them.
is 8 hours a little long for such a query?

Comment: Hi @Mike Brant .. OK Yes, I will add to the question to make it clearer. Thank you.

Comment: you are doing a corellated subquery, which means you're running the subqueries for EVERY row in the the parent update, e.g. if you're updating 50,000 rows, you're also running 50,000 subqueries.

Comment: What version of mysql is this?

Comment: Really for something like this with an update - you could totally eliminate the issue by using a stored procedur.

Comment: I don't see why you need two inner selects. You don't need to select all those fields, only `count(ID)`.

Comment: Thanks @cerd - MySQL Server 5.6

Comment: Thanks Regarding "you are doing a correlated subquery"  @Marc B.
I'm not sure how else to do this - I need to make the calculation for each record.

Comment: Thanks @EJP - I'm not sure. I need to calculate the values of the  records that are relative to every row. So I guess I need to loop each row - and make a calculation for each row. That is why I am grabbing those other fields - so I can calculate their values relative to each row I am comparing.

Comment: Thanks @Mike Brant - I have added some explanation. I hope this is helpful. Thank you for your understanding all.

Comment: @Kreeverp - basically when the word 'loop' enters the picture with MySQL - you'll want a stored procedure. I'll post an answer - I used to spend hours on stuff like this. SPs in MySQL are confusing - but worth every hour spent learning.

Comment: Thanks @cerd - I've got all this working in PHP perfectly - but it takes days for php to process the whole thing on 500000 records. I'm not sure "loops" is the correct term for MySQL - but I'm basically just trying to write the value of a calculation to one record - based on what is found in other records. Its pretty straightforward in PHP (read record, get relative records, calculate, write). I'm trying to transition the logic of my PHP/MySQL queries and loops to pure MySQL, for the purpose of speed.  As you can see - I am having trouble with the transition. Thanks again for any help all : )

Comment: @Kreeverp - Can you give an example of the expected value for BROK_1_RATING for ea. row or 1 or 2 rows?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can shorten the query a lot by just removing the extra stuff:

```
UPDATE `working` as AA SET `BROK_1_RATING` = 
(SELECT COUNT(`ID`) FROM `working` AS BB 
    WHERE BB.`ANNDATS_CONVERTED` <= AA.`ANNDATS_CONVERTED` 
    AND BB.`REVDATS_CONVERTED` > AA.`ANNDATS_CONVERTED`
    AND BB.`ID` != AA.`ID`
    AND BB.`ESTIMID` = AA.`ESTIMID`
    AND BB.`ANALYST` != ''
    AND BB.`IRECCD` = 1 )
WHERE `ANALYST` != '';
```

Comment: Thank you @HerpaMoTeH your answer produces an error "Unknown column 'working.ANALYST' in 'where clause' "

Comment: and if I change WHERE `working`.`ANALYST` != ''; to - WHERE AA.`ANALYST` != ''; I get the error "You can't specify target table 'AA' for update in FROM clause "

Comment: Is ANALYST empty or NULL ? and also instead of != try using <>. Also you can just leave it as ANALYST <> '', there's no need to specuify a table ;)

Comment: This query is illegal as far as mysql is concerned - you can't update a table using a subquery `FROM <table_to_be_updated>`.

Comment: Thanks @cerd it does work - referencing the derived table as an alias `BB`. But it just takes forever on 500,000 records.

Comment: Thanks @HerpaMoTeH - ANALYST is empty. But I don't think that has anything to do with the error. When I run your code - I get:
"You can't specify target table 'AA' for update in FROM clause"